# Does Price Set for Memberships also allow for Recurring on a Donation

Tags: contributions, civimember, price-sets, recurring-contributions

Goal is that a Membership page will have a Price Set that offers Membership (not auto renew) plus 'other amount' that would have option of being set as recurring.
I read http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Price+Sets+for+Recurring+Contributions but it doesn't leave me any wiser (yet).
I set up a Price Set on demo here http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/price/field?reset=1&action=browse&sid=11&new=1 but see no option on the Donation price field to make it recurring.
I confirmed that there is no such option either when I set up a Price Set for a Contribution page, so conclude that for Donations, it uses the 'recurring' settings from the Contribution page settings, but that if we use a Price Set for Memberships, we have to turn off "Contribution Amounts section enabled" and hence concluding that there is no such an option for a Membership page. Is there a way to to this that I have missed?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is resolved in our case by not using Price Set now that I twigged that the 'financial type' setting on the Contribution page ONLY affects the Donations, while it is the 'financial type' setting on the Membership Type that takes care of the other.

> If you are using this contribution page for membership signup and renewals, the financial type configured in the membership type settings will be used when recording the membership payment. The financial type selected here will only be used if you are also collecting additional contributions (as configured on the Membership Settings page).

So the outcome is

- recurring donations work
- donations get recorded as 'donation' financial type
- memberships get recorded as 'membership' financial type